# Format HTML form

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to write a HTML form on a website that after entering the values, the email will then be formatted in a certain way. For example

```
<form action="mailto:randomurl.com?subject=example_subject_in_email" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

    <p><font face="Arial"><font size="2">Name:
    <br /></font><input type="text" name="Name " size="40"/></font></p>

    <p><font face="Arial"><font size="2">Contact Number:
    <br /></font><input type="text" name="Contact Number " size="40"/></font></p>

</form>
```

If you entered 'first' and 'second' in the respective inputs, would result in opening an email client with the following values:

```
Name =first
Contact Number =second
```

However I want to alter this by adding spaces after the '=' character and make it like the following

```
Name = first
Contact Number = second
```

Is there any way to do this without having some backend server with PHP/JS etc?

EDIT:

When running on a web server I get different results sometimes, also accessing the webpage on a phone adds spaces but on macOS is does not if that's relevant?

Comment: Add `&nbsp;` after '='.

Comment: There is no way to answer this with what you've provided. How are the colons being converted to equal signs? What Quinten suggests might work if you know where it goes.

Comment: @Quinten I don't have any control over the `=` character. When clicking a submit button the `name ` attributes get prepended to the value. For example entering `example` into the input with name `name `, would result in `name =example` in the email application

Comment: Like wazz says, you have provided too little information. As it looks now Javascript or PHP are your best options.